# Catch unique constraint exception and retry not working Web API with C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, try-catch, webapi

In Web API running on .NET FW 4.6, I am trying to catch the unique constraint exception and retrying the insert with a new value but it's NOT inserting into SQL Server.

I am using Dapper and I am able to see both the insert statements in Profiler, but I don't see the data in SQL Server. If I do the same code in a console app, it works fine.

```
int retryNum = 0;
var ConfirmationId = string.Empty;

do
{
    try
    {
        // Hashids will set a 6 character code here.
        ConfirmationId = ConfirmationIdGenerator.getConfirmationID();

        // This used dapper SQL to insert into a table having only 
        // 1 column which is  unique PK varchar(6).
        Insert(ConfirmationId);
        break;
    }
    catch (SqlException ex) when (ex.Number == 2627)
    {
        // Generate again
        ConfirmationId = ConfirmationIdGenerator.getConfirmationID();
        retryNum++;
    }
 // It is retrying and I am seeing another INSERT statement hitting 
 // SQL Server through Profiler but I don't see the data. 
 // Is there an issue with Web API NOT inserting if it detects 
 // exception even though we suppress the exception with a catch?
} while (retryNum < 5);
```

Comment: I think you need to look at `IDENTITY` columns, they are generated automatically by the database

Comment: How do you know it is retrying then if you are not seeing another insert? Are you debugging your code?

Comment: Not a solution, just note that the `ConfirmationId = ...` line in the `catch` is needless. You always overwriting that value in `try` block with a new one.

Comment: What data don't you see? If all inserts you see in profiler are causing exception no data will be persisted. Are the _Errors and Warnings_ turned on in profiler? Are any red lines around the insert statement lines in the profiler?

Comment: Hello @Charlieface, thanks for assisting. There is a requirement to generate it from .Net using HASIDS and insert. I have just simplified to a table with one column. But this will be used in a table where this would be a new column.

Comment: Dear @AthanasiosKataras, thanks for assisting, I adding logging in each line. For simplicity I removed and provided the code here.

Comment: Dear @cly, I don't see any errors in profiler. i do see the write count but not seeing data in table.

Comment: Sounds like an odd requirement. Do you have any kind of SQL transaction here? Is implicit transactions on or off `select 2 & @@OPTIONS`? Are you **sure** the error is PK violation, does the final insert succeed when you step through the code?

Comment: Are the _Errors and Warnings_ turned on in profiler? I dont see how could happen that your code receives SqlException but no errors shown in profiler.